# Change height of Add New Post input box

Tags: wp-admin, css

The textarea box on the Add New Post page is too high for my application. I'd like to change it to 260px high. However the style is embedded. What's the best way to change it, without altering the original file?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**EDIT VIA COMMENTS**

```
<?php 
function add_styles() {
?> 
   <style type="text/css"> 
      .wp-editor-container { 
          clear: both; 
          height: 246px !important; 
      } 
   </style> 
<?php }

add_action('wp_head', 'add_styles');
```

Comment: Is there a way to change this css from the functions.php file?

Comment: Try to insert this in your functions.php file:

<?php

function add_styles()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
.wp-editor-container { clear: both; height: 246px !important; }
</style>

    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_styles');

Comment: @EzraJohnAlvarez First, please use [edit]s for additional info. Second, suggesting to edit core files is a very, very bad suggestion.

Comment: Hi kaiser, thanks for the info but where can i find that edits you're talking, sorry just new here..and yea you're right, forgot it will be overwritten when updating wordpress...

Comment: Editing on the server isn't cool, either.

Comment: There are multiple links on the lower left of your answer. One of them is "[edit]".

Comment: I have taken the liberty and added your code from your comment. Just go and add a proper explanation to what your code does. Lets get these downvotes removed and gain yourself proper reputation points

Comment: Just remember, these changes should go into a child theme :)